How to remove the blank gap on the last element of the card
I want the cards to be evenly spread out across the page from left to right. However at the current stage there's a massive gap to the right. I've tried to use the 'last-child' class in CSS, but it wasn't  successful
{% block content %}
<style>

    .card-container {
        display: flex;
    }

    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transition: 0.3s;
        height: 25%;
        width: 25vw;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        height: 250px;
    }

    .card:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .container {
        padding: 2px 16px;
    }
</style>

<div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="download.png" alt="Statistic" style="width:25%, height:125% ">
        <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Jon Doe</b></h4>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <img src="download.png" alt="Statistic" style="width:25%, height:125% ">
        <div class="container">
            <h4><b>Jon Doe</b></h4>
            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
{% endblock %}


justify-content: space-between  on the container?

Still has a massive gap on the right side of the screen. not sure why though

Apply this CSS to the main container:
.container {
   width: 100vw;
}


 .card-body {
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     padding: 1rem 1rem;
     display: flex;    
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: space-between;

Try this!.

Still has a massive gap on the right side of the screen. not sure why though

could be becuase of your flexbox configuration.  Is it happening on different types of screens?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
